# switching from Apache to Nginx : PHPExcel no longer works

Tags: apache, nginx, phpexcel

I was on `Apache 2.2` and somewhere on my application I was generating Excel document with `PHPExcel`. **It was working fine**.

I switched to `Nginx /php5-fpm` and since then **the generated file is unreadable**. I tried removing all the optimization under nginx vhost/conf.

Apache Response Headers (Readable excel file):

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Export-3339-Lettre d'actualitÃ© clients.xls"
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel
Date:Mon, 22 Sep 2014 12:24:35 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.16 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.16
```

Nginx Response Headers (messy file):

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Export-3339-Lettre d'actualitÃ© clients.xls"
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel
Date:Mon, 22 Sep 2014 12:22:02 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
```

The file looks like :
[image]

*EDIT** After turning off `chunked_transfer_encoding` here's the response headers, but still no valid generated document.

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Export-3339-Lettre d'actualit%C3%A9 clients.xls"
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel
Date:Wed, 24 Sep 2014 09:53:34 GMT
Server:nginx
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
```

Comment: The obvious difference is the KeepAlive connection. Have you tried without KeepAlive? Well and the chunked encoding. No clue why this application is sensitive to it, but investigate it.

Comment: Seems that I can't turn off KeepAlive in nginx without patching the core :/

Comment: I would try this first: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: turning it off makes no difference, i've updated my question to reflect it.

Comment: Well, two options leftin my mind: character set and compression. Both servers don't send a character set, so it's unlikely but possible that the php script expects some setting that is missing in the nginx config. Compression is more likely. Is it possible you're sending a gzip compressed file? If none of this pans out, if it's a recent Excel format it's simply zipped XML documents, so perhaps you can find some differences there, that provide a hint to what's going on.

Comment: I'll investigate into the character set, which seems to me like a good lead. Have you any tips on what to try/search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, it the way the response was generated and returned.

`file_get_content()` instead of `readfile()` fixed it.